# NGINX: Location matches assests

Tags: nginx, regex

I'm having issues where my location is matching a resource one server should be serving because it has the some format as a directory

With this configuration:

```
location ~ "/web/" {
    set $upstream_host http://webServer;
    set $upstream_port 1234;
    set $upstream_server "${upstream_host}:$upstream_port";

    proxy_pass $upstream_server;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_redirect off;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://staticHomePageServer;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Works - https://my.example.com/web/

Works - https://my.example.com/someOtherSub/web.jpg

Does Not Works - https://my.example.com/web (404)

and if I change

```
location ~ "/web/" {
```

to

```
location ~ "/web" {
```

Then the sub directory redirects work but I get a 404 on the jpg

Comment: Show the full config with `nginx -T`. Show the full log line for the failed requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried anchoring your regex?

```
location ~ "^/web" {
```